# Hide Component on specific route - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where the routes are defined as follows.

```
return ((
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" render={ () => (token && <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/dashboard'
      }}/>) || <Login />}
      />
      <Route path="/logout" render={ () => !token && <Login />} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}  { ...this.props }/>
    </Switch>
    </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
));
```

Using this approach, the header component will be rendered on all pages.

But i don't want the header to be displayed on the home page or the login page.

The only way i found to tackle this issue is to remove the header from the above code and call the header component individually inside each component.

Is there any alternate way to hide the Header component for specific pages based on the above approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an additional [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component which renders nothing for the `/` and `/login` routes, but renders the `Header` component for every other route.

```
return (
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" />
        <Route path="/login" />
        <Route path="/" component={Header} />
      </Switch>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/login"
          render={() =>
            token ? (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/dashboard"
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <Login />
            )
          }
        />
        <Route path="/logout" render={() => !token && <Login />} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} {...this.props} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
);
```